# VMWare ESXi Virtual SAN

Tags: vmware, esxi

I am doing some research on VMWare VSAN because we are looking at our options for storage. I am getting mixed answers when I Google. We are building a new host in our new office and we are starting fresh. Our old setup we had a server host HP with a few drives which ESXi connected to a SAN and we used a combination of both for storage of VM's and file storage. We did not use VSAN, but with the new setup this is definitely an option. We are looking at a HP ProLiant DL380 GEN9 server that is capable of holding several drives. If I loaded this up with large drives and setup VSAN, would this be a good option for a file storage server? This host will also host several other VM's as well.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on ServerFault.com?

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you want to do the hardware refresh and system architecture reconfiguration. Correct me if I`m wrong.

If so, then IMHO the best way gonna be to go with one of the hyper-converged solutions. Is see three options here:

- Simplivity (https://www.simplivity.com/). Its really good, but it was too high cost for one of the projects that I had. Also its perfromance is mostly bottlenecked by the propritory component (FPGA), which in most of cases means lack of flexibility
- VMware VSAN (I'm sure you don't need link for that :) ). According to my friend who works at VMware - it is usually considered for big deployments. so if that is your case - go for it.
- StarWind Hyper-Converged Appliance (https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-hyperconverged-appliance ). That one is SMB-oriented. It combines commodity Dell hardware and bunch of software. Since everything is commodity - it is easy to handle.

I hope that makes gonna help.

P.S. I`m not sure if this is the best place to ask this Q, possible serverfault would be the better place.

Answer (score 1):

Fault tolerant file storage is possible with VMware Virtual SAN but kind of expensive. Either way VMware does solve storage redundancy for running VMs but it does not solve the issue with exporting SMB 3.0 or NFS v4.1 mount points you'll need, you have to use custom VMs for that. FreeBSD / Linux with Samba for NFS and Windows / Hyper-V Server for SMB 3.0 will do the trick!

Similar discussion on REDDIT some time ago lots of good thoughts.

https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/4223ol/virtual_san_for_file_servers/